# How to enable coffeescript support in couchdb?

Tags: coffeescript, couchdb

I am building couchdb from source using:

https://github.com/iriscouch/build-couchdb/

How do I enable coffeescript as a query language? This option appears on iriscouch's cloud server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CouchDB 1.2.0 have build-in coffeescript query server. 
[Feature discussion](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-817?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like building the latest version from source includes this.

Answer (score 0):

A more specific answer if you are running CouchDB 1.2.0 or higher:

On your design document add a property called "language" and set the value to "coffeescript". This seems to make all views expect coffeescript. It doesn't seem possible to have some views be done in javascript and some in coffeescript.

Comment: It's a little hacky, but if you need javascript within coffeescript you can wrap your javascript in backticks.

Comment: That's a reasonable alternative. I wish you could specify it with a property for each view object though. Then your couchapp script could set it based on the file extension or something.